# Facebook login Image

Tags: facebook, symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2.4 with FOS User Bundle , FOS Facebook Bundle and Sonata Bundles.
My Question is How I can hidden facebook login image which used by default in fos facebook bundle under our custom Image?

Default facebook login Image : [image]

And I want this :

[image]

How I can do this?
I used this :

```
{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();'}) }}
{{ facebook_login_button({'autologoutlink': true}) }}
```

Which show by defaul fb Image.

In my twig file :

```
<a class="facebook" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
```

Comment: this may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623778/custom-facebook-fosfacebookbundle-login-button

Comment: @zizoujab this not my question

Answer (score 2):

you have to override the twig facebook_login_button function to add you picture.

the to overrid is [FOSFacebookBundle/Resources/views/loginButton.html.twig](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/loginButton.html.twig).

Or more simple override CSS properties of .fb-login-button class.